# One-line object declaration in rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is it possible to declare `Marker` from `visualization_msgs.msg` in one line? Below is my code:

```
from std_msgs.msg import ColorRGBA
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker

red   = ColorRGBA(0.98, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
fixed_frame = 'base'

my_marker = Marker()
my_marker.id  = 0
my_marker.ns = 'my_marker'
my_marker.color = red
my_marker.action = Marker.ADD
my_marker.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
my_marker.scale.x = float(line_width)
my_marker.header.stamp = time
my_marker.header.frame_id = fixed_frame
```

I am using ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274713/one-line-object-declaration-in-rospy/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this page on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Messages), you can use in-order or keyword arguments to initialize the values during construction. Your code would then look like this:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from std_msgs.msg import ColorRGBA, Header
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker

red   = ColorRGBA(0.98, 0.30, 0.30, 1.00)
fixed_frame = 'base'
my_marker = Marker(id  = 0,
                   ns = 'my_marker',
                   color = red,
                   action = Marker.ADD,
                   type = Marker.LINE_STRIP,
                   scale = Pose(x=float(line_width)),
                   header = Header(stamp = time, frame_id = fixed_frame))
```

If you're generating a lot of markers, you might want to look at David Lu!!'s [easy_markers package](http://wiki.ros.org/easy_markers).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-01**:
Which really doesn't look that different from the "multi-line" initialisation style :)

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-11-01**:
Yeah, it's not really better.